# All elements after vue component are removed automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Please check out [this page](https://mayank1513.github.io/tag-input/demo.html) and its [source code](https://github.com/mayank1513/tag-input/blob/master/demo.html). If I remove the cdn for the [vue-tag-input](https://github.com/mayank1513/tag-input) component, everything except the component renders. But as soon as I add the cdn back, everything after first instance of tag-input component is not rendered on DOM. No error logs.

Please help me understand what is going on. As far as I understand there should not be any issue with component as I can render multiple instances and the same page layout in vue app using cdn. Check out [App.vue](https://github.com/mayank1513/tag-input/blob/master/src/App.vue) file as well. This works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When vue component is used directly inside the html (not in single file vue component template), we need to take care of [certain things](https://www.udemy.com/course/vuejs-complete-course-plus-guide/?couponCode=HAPPY_LEARNING)

1. Don't use self closing tag for the component
2. convert all camel case to kebab case for component name and all the props (custom attributes)

There were above two errors because of which the implementation in question was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use valid html5 so you can't use self closing tags.

Change `<tag-input v-model="tags" />` to `<tag-input v-model="tags"></tag-input>`